# Understanding the basics of index in SQL

Tags: sql, indexing

```
SELECT  *  
FROM    Movies  
WHERE   studioName =    ‘Disney’    AND year    =   1990;
```

How much    would   each    of  these       indexes help?

```
CREATE  INDEX   YearIndex ON    Movies(year);  
CREATE  INDEX   StudioIndex ON  Movies(studioName);  
CREATE  INDEX   YSIndex ON  Movies(year,studioName);  
CREATE  INDEX   SYIndex ON  Movies(studioName,year);
```

How much would each index help if the WHERE clause was year = 1990?

Creating an index on year would indeed help because there are lot of years in which movies were created, so the search would be minimized substantially.

```
Studioname
```

would help as well but not as much as year because there are more years than studionames.

```
year,studioname
```

is the better choice in this case because obviously the search is minimized by more than the previous two

```
studioname,year
```

is good but not as good as the previous.

How much would each of the indexes help if the WHERE clause was year <  1990?

Indexing on studioname would help more than indexing on year because in this case we have to look up all years less than 1990, so if we index on year, we would have to search the paths of all years less than 1990, so I think that indexing on studioname, year is the better option.

Is this the correct way to think about this?

Comment: (year, studioName) and (studioName, year) indexes are probably equivalent if you’re looking up both of them, and in Postgres at least, searching on the first column of an index is only slightly more efficient than searching on the second one (because it can read prefixes of indexes). Not sure what “all years less than 1990” means.

Comment: Which DBMS? How large is the Movies table? What is the cardinality of each of the proposed indexes?

Comment: All years less than 1990 ummm. I think that the use of the word every would fix the misunderstood. "Every year less than 1990"

Comment: Oh wait sorrry, I detected a typo in the second question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the index on (year, studioName) is the best. It allows a fast lookup when you have conditions on both columns.

If you have a second query that only searches for year, but not for studioName, then the same index would also help.

But if you only had an index on (studioName, year), and you search only for a specific year, the index would not help.

Think of a telephone book. You can search for people by last name because that's how the book is sorted. You can also search for people by last and first name, and the book helps even more.

But if you search only for people with a given first name, the sort order of the book isn't much help.

You might like my presentation, [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or the video of me presenting it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

The presentation is tailored for MySQL, but many of the ideas apply to any database that implements indexes using B-tree structures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I detected a typo in the second question.